# Search through an array of objects and return whole object if a value matches a string or substring

Tags: javascript, search, javascript-objects

I have multiple objects in an array (I shortened the example, so it doesn't make much sense, but I think it's better to understand the problem):

```
address_components: [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "41",
        types: "street_number"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Tal",
        types: "route"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "München",
        types: "city"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "Deutschland",
        types: "country, political"
    },
]
```

I want to look through these objects and search for a type, like "country". If a type "country" is found I want the whole object back, so:

```
{
    id: 4,
    name: "Deutschland"
    types: "country, political"
}
```

I got the following approach:

```
var searchFor = "city";
var addressComponent = response.address_components.filter(function(e) {
    return searchFor.indexOf(e.types) != -1;
});
```

Which works if I search for "city", but not if I search for a substring(?) like "country".
Is this approach correct and can I extend it somehow to return the correct result if I sear for "country" in my example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that *country* is the sub-string of types then simply **Do it the other way round**

```
return e.types.indexOf( searchFor ) != -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You inversed things.
 return e.types.indexOf(searchFor) != -1;

```js
  var address_components = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "41",
            types: "street_number"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Tal",
            types: "route"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: "München",
            types: "city"
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            name: "Deutschland",
            types: "country,political"
        }
    ]
    
    var searchFor = "political";
    
    var response = address_components.filter(function(e) {
        return e.types.indexOf(searchFor) != -1;
    });
    
    console.log(response);
```